# In scalaz stream, how can i turn a Process[Task,Seq<B>] into a Process1[Task,B]

Tags: scalaz-stream

I have a Process[Task,A]. A contains a Seq of Bs

```
case class A(elems:Seq[B])
```

I would like to transform the Process[Task,A] into a Process[Task,B]

```
def streamOfAs:Process[Task,A] = ???

streamOfBs1:Process[Task,Member] = streamOfAs.flatMap(Process.emit(_.elems)) //Compiler error
streamOfBs2:Process[Task,Member] = streamOfAs pipe process1.lift((a:A) => a.elems) //yields Process[Task,Seq[B]]
```

are there any buildtin functions to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the case class A is essentially function A => Seq[B]

then solution would be perhaps

```
val sourceB: Process[Task,B] = sourceA.flatMap(emitAll(_.elems))
```

Comment: You are right. But there seems to be some weirdness with my IDE: When i let the compiler infer the type, i indeed get Process[Task,B], but when i explicitly set the type, i get a compiler error.